# Android Screen Type/Brightness

Tags: android, screen, brightness

Is there a way to get info about screen type in android?
I want to know is device i am using amoled/ips/tft or get maximum brightness of screen, not relative brightness but brightness in nits or candelas/cm2

Answer (score 0):

Much like other physical aspects of a device(weight, length, moment of inertia, etc.), this information will not be stored in the phone. I think the only way you could do this is to gather the information, create a database, and reference values to device IDs.

Edit: The only other thing I can think of is using the device's light sensor and some sort of calibration device/method.
Something like:

- hold device x distance from a mirror/white surface in a pitch black room
- programmatically cycle the screen through brightness settings
- read light sensor at each step

The limitations here would be in the light sensor if it even exists and getting people to calibrate their device properly.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there's any way to do it directly, but you can get the device name using

```
android.os.Build.MODEL;
```

and then use this to do some sort of web service for the information you need.